# cannot apply indexing with [] to an express of type 'method group, (how to print array)

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

i have array that call nums, it contain int var.
the array is 2d -

```
int[,] nums = new int[lines, row];
```

i need to print each line in the array in other line.

when i try to print to array like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 46; j++)
                Console.Write(nums[i,j]);
```

** when i using the above syntax i dont get an error in visual studio, but when i run the program, i got error in this line -  Console.Write(nums[i,j]);.

error - system.IndeOutOfRangeException.

i got the error , i try to change the syntax to this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 46; j++)
                Console.Write(nums[i][j]);
```

the error: "wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2"

and:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 46; j++)
                Console.Write(nums[i][j].tostring());
```

**update**

i am so stupid... i write 46(number in my program) instead of 6(numbers in each row) thats whey is was out of range.

ty for all, and i am sry to open a question with such bad problem...

TY!

Comment: If you get that error, `nums` must be a method. Are you sure you declared it as a variable?

Comment: lines is a int number. i am sure that i declared all of the vars.
i am using them in all my code.

Comment: Please specify the exact error you get for all three examples you gave.

Comment: Well, the ACTUAL error says you passed a wrong index number! Looks like `row` is less than 46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *lines* and *row* are positive integer values, say, `int lines = 5; int row = 7;` you can print out your table like this:

```
  int[,] nums = new int[lines, row]; // <- Multidimensional (2 in this case) array, not an array of array which is nums[][]

  //TODO: fill nums with values, otherwise nums will be all zeros

  for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(); // <- let's start each array's line with a new line

    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) { // <- What the magic number "46" is? "row" should be here... 
      Console.Write(nums[i, j]); // <- nums[i, j].ToString() doesn't spoil the output

      if (j > 0) // <- let's separate values by spaces "1 2 3 4" instead of "1234"
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
  }
```

Comment: @doron hine: Try to avoid magic numbers like 6 or 46: what "6" stands for? Put "row" instead, or compute a value:
"nums.GetLength(1)"

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with 2 different types of arrays

```
int[,] nums = new int[lines, row];
```

is a [Multi-Dimensional Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). Elements of the array can be accessed using **nums[x,y]**.

When you use **nums[x][y]** you are dealing with an array of arrays.

You cannot use array of arrays syntax with a multi-dimensional array.

You might try [What are the differences between Multidimensional array and Array of Arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c) for details.